# Jenkins job doesnt continue after starting selenium server

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a jenkins job that needs to run some tests against a selenium server. I have have defined a stage where I start the selenium server in 1 container, and after that I want to run my tests from another container, against the selenium server.

The selenium server seems to start fine, but after that the job just hangs, displaying a spinner:

[image]

This is what my pipeline script looks like:

```
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      defaultContainer 'jnlp'
      yaml """
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        spec:
            containers:
              - name: node
                image: node:12.14.1
              - name: selenium
                image: vvoyer/selenium-standalone  
      """
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout codebase') {
      // do checkout
    }
    stage('start selenium') {
      steps {
        container('selenium') {
            sh '''
                selenium-standalone install
                selenium-standalone start       //script hangs after this command
            '''
        }
      }
    }
    stage('test') {
      steps {
        container('node') {
            //build test project & run tests
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here and how I can fix it?

Comment: Probably `selenium-standalone start` starts the server in the foreground and waits until something stops it? If you want your script to continue, you need to start it in the background.

Comment: That was the case, I added an & at the end of my command and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Thanks, solved similar error by adding '&' at the end of shell script step inside Jenkinsfile.
ex:
sh label: '',script: 'docker-compose -f TestAutomation_UI_API/docker-compose-v3.yml up --scale chrome=3 **&**'